# Relation between the euclidean space and a set of functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $n$ be an integer. In what sense can $\mathbb{R}^n$ be seen as the collection of functions $\lbrace n\to \mathbb{R}\rbrace$? (-what is $n$ here?) And also, does this (bijection of sets, I guess?) extend to an isomorphism of grous or vector spaces or any other structure that has these sets underlying it?

Answer (score 1):

Each element $v$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is caracterized by its $n$ components : $v = (v_{1}, ..., v_{n})$. You could just see a vector $v$ as a function from the set $\{1,...,n\} \to \mathbb{R}$ : the image of the element $i$ is the $i$-th coordinate. This is why some people write $v(i)$ for vector coordinates. This notation is usually seen in sequences : a sequence is nothing but a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

The notation $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a shorthand for $\mathbb{R}^{\{1, ..., n\}}$ : we usually note $A^{B}$ the set of functions from $B$ to $A$, where $A$ and $B$ could be any sets.

Answer (score 0):

In set theory, we often define natural numbers to be the finite Von Neumann ordinals: in particular, $n$ is the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$, which makes it suitable to be the index set for a sequence of length $n$.